# Nested loop for python

Tags: python, nested

I have problem with a nested loop problem. In a year, I want my loop to add up every number from the month of the year. When the year is over instead of adding the numbers from last year  and adding it to the new year, i want it to begin again at 0.

Finally, it should show me the total of each year and give me an average of all the years.

Here is my sample if anyone could help me finish it:

```
total_rain = 0
month = 12
y = 0
rain = 0
month_rain = 0
years = int(input("How many years: "))

for y in range(years):
    y += 1
    print()
    print("In the year", y,"There will be:")

    for m in range(month):
        rain = float(input('How many inch of rainfall have fallen: ')) 
    total_rain += rain
    print(month_rain)
main()
```

Every time a loop ends, it adds the number from the previous year. I want the new loop to start at 0 again and add up the numbers.

Comment: Do not increase `y` in the loop. The `for` already does that.

Comment: @jspurim: OP is implementing `for y in range(1, years+1)`

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: why you call main(), is it necessary?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Ohh I understand. Anyway, he should do that instead of iterating one value below and correcting on each iteration.

Comment: @jspurim: totally agree. Check out my answer, where I do exactly that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for y in range(years):
    y += 1
    for m in range(month):
        rain = float(input('How many inch of rainfall have fallen: '))
        total_rain += rain
    print("In the year", y,"There will be:", total_rain," inches of rain")
    #reset variable
    total_rain = 0
```

First of all, I corrected the indentation of "total_rain += rain" because you had it nested outside of the 2nd for loop, therefore it wouldn't actually add the rain you input each time.

Then all I did was set the total rain to 0 to reset it.

It works like a charm and is very similar to your own code.

Comment: Great. Please consider to mark my answer as accepted. (Click on the gray check mark to the left of my answer to accept it)

Answer (score 0):

```
total_rain = 0
month = 12
rain = 0
years = int(input("How many years: "))

for y in range(years):
    month_rain = 0
    print()
    print("In the year", y,"There will be:")

    for m in range(month):
        rain = float(input('How many inch of rainfall have fallen: ')) 
        month_rain += rain
    total_rain += month_rain
    print("year %s: %s" % (y, month_rain) )
print("total rain: %s" % (total_rain/years))
```

Comment: can you explain why print out month_rain if you never use it?

Comment: It was only to check if my program worked correctly. I'm new in python so i always do this to be sure my program do what i ask for.

Comment: @haifzhan Thanks! I forgot to acumulate it. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_rain = []
months = 12
years = int(input("How many years: "))
for y in range(1, years+1):
    print("In the year", y,"There will be:")
    annual_rain = []
    for m in range(1,13):
        rain = float(input('How many inch of rainfall have fallen in month %s: ' %m))
        annual_rain.append(rain)
    total_rain.append(annual_rain)

for y,year in enumerate(total_rain, 1):
    print("Total rain in year %s: %s. Average monthly rain: %s" %(y, sum(year), sum(year)/len(year)))
```

Comment: I am still on chapter 5 of my book, 'Repetition structure' so i didn't get to the list chapter yet but i will save your work and when i'll get to the list chapter check your work and try to understand the steps. Thank you!